# Run Jar file with specific static method instead of the main in terminal

Tags: java, command-line, jar, static

I have a jar file, and I need to use a static method on that. I try to run the command as following from the terminal, but it always runs the main function.

```
java -cp myJarFile.jar:com.test.ClassA ClassA StaticMethodA "arg1"
```

It always uses main function instead of StaticMethodA... Who can help me with this issue? I just want the result of StaticMethodA("arg1").

Thanks.

Comment: you can wrap your method by main() method. But in java you should have a starting point.

Comment: Use the args (inside your main) to determine the static methoths you want to call, and then pass the following args to your special static method.

Answer (score 0):

Main method is entry point for you class which designed to be runner. In main method call your static method by passing argument to it.

Comment: but I lose the source code of this program. I need to run that method in the terminal...:(